# Turn on indexing for files but not directories

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I want to serve a specific location to a directory, like so:

```
location /media/ {
    autoindex on;
    root /path/to/some/media/dir;
}
```

The above works, but it also allows users to go to directories and see a list of all the files in there. I would like the files to be accessible, but directories not to show any index.

What should happen instead is not very important to me, whether a 404, 403, or not match the location block at all, but I would prefer the latter.

Comment: `autoindex` shows the contents of directories. Are you saying that you want to see the contents of the `/media/` directory, but prevent showing the contents of any subdirectory below it?

Comment: If I use the above without `autoindex on;` the files are inaccessible as well as the directories. I want just the files to be accessible, but not the directories.